# Blend for visual studio 2012 connect to team foundation server 2012 server everytime blend gain focus

Tags: tfs, blend, blend-2012

I'm working with visual studio 2012 and blend for visual studio 2012 simultaneously. The problem i have is that every time I switch to blend, it tries to connect to team foundation server causing about 10 seconds delays. This gets annoying real fast since I switch between blend and visual studio rapidly. I did block blend in firewall, but blend tries to connect until timeout.

is there a way to disable blend to connect to team foundation server?

Comment: Am i the only one experiencing this problem?

Comment: I found this happening as well until I upgraded to VS2012 Release 2. Are you running this version?

Comment: as of now im using the latest(2013). Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go `Offline TFS`

Follow theses steps :

1.Using Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Team Explorer, open the solution file, and then, in the Go Offline dialog box that appears, click OK. For more information, see How to: Work Offline when the Server is Unavailable  on MSDN.

2.Open the solution in Expression Blend and make your changes. When you save files, Expression Blend displays a Save of Read-Only File dialog box. Click Overwrite to remove the write-protection from the file.

3.When the Team Foundation server is available again, use the procedure at How to: Work Offline when the Server is Unavailable  to go back online. If another team member made changes to the file while you had it checked out, you might need to resolve conflicts.

article about your case : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341367(v=expression.40).aspx